# Get Navigation Title Width always return 0 value?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

In the ViewWillApear I do the following code: (`theTitle` has a string value)

```
self.navigationItem.title =  theTitle;

DLog(@"Title Width : %f", CGRectGetWidth(self.navigationItem.titleView.frame));
```

I always get `Title Width : 0.000000`. I also tried the following code and I also have 0 value

```
CGRect titleViewFrame = [self.navigationItem.titleView convertRect:self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds toView:self.view];
DLog(@"%f", titleViewFrame.size.width);
```

Thnaks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When presented with a `UINavigationController` the navigationItem object of a view controller is nil.

You can get the frame you want by using the navigationItem of the navigationController:

```
[[[self.navigationController navigationItem] titleView] frame]
```

Comment: Unfortunately if doen't for me ? I have the same problem with 0 value.

Comment: Is your view controller presented by a UINavigationController? Can you set a breakpoint in viewWillAppear and `po` all the objects to see if anything is nil (`po [self.navigationController navigationItem]` and so on)

Comment: in _navigationItem, _title is set, but _titleView is nil.  I need to know the width of the title ?

Comment: Just checked, have I to get the value in self.navigationController.navigationItem.navigationBar.titleView ?

Beacause here the titleView is not nil.

Comment: Don't have access to ...navigationItem.navigationBar

Comment: Found a solution : not using the self.navigationItem.title, but creating a temp label and set the label to the self.navigationItem.titleView before getting the size.
Thanks Mark, with your idea, i found a solution.